# Magento product 404

Tags: magento-1.7

I have an strange problem with Magento. One product categorie show an 404 page. All the other categories works just fine.

I have check the rewrite, cache, re-indext everything. 
What can it possible be?

1.7.0.2

Comment: Error log: codepen.io/Goldenmonky/post/voor-log

Comment: Also getting an 404 by going to Magento Downloader